# Softlayer API: previous Billing cycle Billing Item Details

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any API where I can fetch previous Billing cycle Billing Item Details. Like how many devices have been created and for how many hours the device has been used,amount charged etc..

Answer (score 0):

See http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account

there you can see all the methods available, perhaps this one can help you:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices

here an example using the PHP client to get the invoices in a dterminate range of date

https://softlayer.github.io/php/get_invoice/

The method will return all the invoices in your account you just need to filter them using the createDate and the closedDate.

About the usage of the device, I think you are refering to the hoursUsed parameter, that parameter is not displayed because is calculated for every billing cicle, but you can calculate that values having the date when the machine has been created and the dates when the billing cicle started and when it ended.

Regards

Comment: Applying Filter on Rest API "https://Username:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems?objectFilter={   "nextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems": {  "nextBillDate":{             "operation": "betweenDate"  "options" : [{    "name": "startDate",    "value": "2017-02-20T13:05:25-06:00"    },    {    "name": "endDate",    "value": "2017-03-20T09:53:51-06:00"    }]  }  }  }"

Comment: But i am getting  "error": "Unable to parse object filter.", can i know where i am making mistake.

Comment: Got it, ',' is missing between operation and options, working fine now.