# Softlayer :: Billing_Info_Cycle not working

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any Softlayer API to get previousCycleStartDate,nextCycleStartDate of an particular Account.
I tryed Billing_Info_Cycle, but it's giving below Error

https://Username:API_Key@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/Billing_Info_Cycle.json

{
  "error": "Service does not exist",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}

Answer (score 1):

I've already answer a similar question

[Softlayer API: previous Billing cycle Billing Item Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625053/softlayer-api-previous-billing-cycle-billing-item-details)

I do not know where do you find the method that you are trying to use, buit I did not find it in [documentation](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account), so the error is fine because the service does not exist.

maybe this is he service that you want to use:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Info

Comment: can find that method here http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Info_Cycle

Comment: Ok that is datatypes that the API uses to diplsy the information, but as you can see in documentation it does not exposes any method that's why you are getting the issue, there is not any method assoiated to it only is used to display data

Comment: In that similar question it say's about Softlayer_Account, but i am looking for nextInvoiceDate, previousInvoiceDate of an particular Account.

Comment: oh try these methods http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Info/getLastBillDate http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Info/getNextBillDate

Comment: For use the methods in my last comment you need to know the id of the billing info for that you can use this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBillingInfo the use that id in the methods e.g.    https://Username:API_Key@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Info/$ID/getLastBillDate

Comment: let me know if you have issue with those methods regards

Comment: found "currentBillingCycle" useful,Thanks for your Response.